# hidden form is sending wrong value

Tags: php, html

that was working very well but i don't why something were spoiled and i can't fix it.The problem is that when i try to get a value of "hidden input" i always receive only the biggest value of all id.Hidden input help me to know wchich button was clicked in table.Please,give me some tips :(

```
<?php

include_once '../config.php';
check_doctor();

db_connect();
echo "  <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='table table-striped'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Imie</th>
              <th>Nazwisko</th>
              <th>NR.PWZ</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
$sql = "SELECT `lekarz_id` ,`lekarz_imie` ,`lekarz_nazwisko` ,`lekarz_pwz` FROM         `lekarze` ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$num_tables = mysql_num_rows($result);
$string="   ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$id = $row[0];

            echo'   <tr>
                <td>'.$row[0].'</a></td>
                <td>'.$row[1].'</a></td>
                                    <td>'.$row[2].'</a></td>
                    <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
                   <td>
                <input type="submit" name="przypisz" class="btn btn-          primary btn-medium" value="Wyślij propozycje" id='.$id.' />
                <input type="hidden" name="lekarz_id" value='.$id.'    />

                   </td>
                   </tr>';
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
  </div>
 </div>

<?
if(isset($_POST['przypisz']))
{
$user_data = get_user_data_p();


$sender = "P".$_SESSION['pacjent_id'];

$recipient="L".$_POST['lekarz_id'];
echo $recipient;


$once="SELECT `message_id` FROM `messages` WHERE `message_title`= 'LP' AND        `message_recipient`='".$recipient."' AND `message_sender`='".$sender."'";
$result = mysql_query($once) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if($row[0] > 0) {
        echo '<p>Już wysłałeś propozycje do tego lekarza.</p>';
        } 
        else
                    {
        $query="INSERT INTO `messages`(`message_title`, `message_text`,    `message_recipient`, `message_sender`, `message_status`, `date_of_posting`)
                    VALUES ('LP','lekarzu,czy jestes w stanie prowadzic   pacjenta?','".$recipient."','".$sender."','nieprzeczytana',Now())";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "'$sender' Propozycja do lekarza '$recipent' została wysłana";
        }
db_close($db);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You are assigning the value to $id in your loop. Take it out of there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the HTML being generated by this script. You will notice **multiple** hidden fields with the name, `"lekarz_id"`, in one form.

When this form is submitted to the server, the `$_POST['lekarz_id']` variable is repeatedly assigned the multiple values from that hidden form field, one at a time. The result is that `$_POST['lekarz_id']` ends up containing the last (which happens to be the biggest) value of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the same **name**  attribute (name="lekarz_id") in the loop. The value of it gets reassigned each time and the maximum value of id will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do in while : value="'.$id.'"